# Confusion regarding how this snippet uses pointers and references to display the time

Tags: c, datetime

This is the (pretty common, I'll add) code that you find for displaying the current in time in C and C++.

```
time_t tt; 
struct tm * ti; 
time (&tt); 
ti = localtime(&tt);
cout << asctime(ti);
```

This is what I do understand:

1. time_t is the data type that stores time values. tt is an object of that.
2. struct tm is a structure in the ctime header file.
3. I can't seem to wrap my head around what ti is. It seems to be a pointer object of tm, but why is the "struct" keyword being used here? Isn't tm an already existing structure?
4. What is time(&tt)? Storing the value of time in tt?

Comment: 3: You use the bonus `struct` keyword because you had to in C.

Comment: pretty common in C++? not really....

Comment: [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) would be the way to go today in C++.

Comment: In both C and C++, the ampersand (`&`) applied to an *expression* is the "address-of" operator and produces a pointer. In C++, `&` in a *type* indicates a reference type. There are no references here.

Comment: BTW - there are no references here - as your question mentions. The `&tt` is getting the address of `tt` in each case. This is C, not C++.

Comment: @user463035818 my bad! Sadly, the compiler and books I'm using are very old (I'm using DOSBOX, Turbo C++) thanks to the syllabus of my school, which is why I turned a blind eye to it. :P

Comment: Much of my confusion was because this code is C code being used in C++. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

1. You're (partially) right. `tt` is not an *object*, it's a *variable of type time_t*
2. Yup
3. `struct tm *` is a datatype: a pointer to a `struct tm`. If you are not familiar with this, try to implement in pure C a stack or a queue or a chained list.
4. RTFM: from the doc (`man 2 time`)

> time_t time(time_t *tloc);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
>         (UTC).
>
> **If tloc is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by tloc.**

So yes, the time is now stored in `ti` and in `tt`.
See [What is the difference between clock_t, time_t and struct tm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240059/what-is-the-difference-between-clock-t-time-t-and-struct-tm)

Answer (score 0):

```
time_t tt;  // a data type to store the number of seconds since the epoch
struct tm * ti;  // a structure that stores the number of seconds decoded into
                 // integers for year, month, day, hour, etc
time (&tt);      // get the current time and store it in tt
ti = localtime(&tt);  //decode the seconds into separate year/month/day/etc ints
cout << asctime(ti);  // convert the ints into string representation and print it
```